# Mongo Java driver not obeying limit method

Tags: java, mongodb

I have this query

```
DBCursor mongoCursor = mongoCollection.find(query).sort(sort).limit(5000);
long mongoCursorCount = mongoCursor.count();
myLogger.info("mongoCursorCount " + mongoCursorCount);
```

which is showing a mongoCursorCount value of 1.2M docs

The limit method works in shell queries but does it work via the mongo-java-driver-2.1.1.jar driver?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default MongoDB ignores `limit` and `skip` when they are applied together with `count`. To change this behavior you need to set `applySkipLimit` to `true`. See [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/) for more details.

In Mongo shell this will ignore the `limit` and `skip` by default:

```
db.coll.find().limit(3).count();
```

And this will respect those modifiers:

```
db.coll.find().limit(3).count(true);
```

It could be possible that you are using an older version of Mongo shell where this is not default or something like that.

To fix your Java code use `size()` instead of `count()` - that's like calling `count(true)` instead of `count()` in shell.