# Are cursor.size() and cursor.count(true) equivalent?

Tags: mongodb

The [`cursor.count()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/#cursor.count) method's `applySkipLimit` boolean parameter is documented as follows:

> ... Specifies whether to consider the effects of the `cursor.skip()` and `cursor.limit()` methods in the count. ... Set `applySkipLimit` to `true` to consider the effect of these methods.

Meanwhile, the [`cursor.size()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.size/#cursor.size) method is documented as follows:

> **Returns:** A count of the number of documents that match the `db.collection.find()` query after applying any `cursor.skip()` and `cursor.limit()` methods.

This makes it sound as though `cursor.count(true)` and `cursor.size()` have identical behaviour, yet the docs for some reason neither confirm or disconfirm this explicitly, and it would seem to be an odd design decision to provide both if they behave identically. Are these two expressions, in fact, equivalent, or is there a subtle difference?

Comment: Related but not the same - the difference between `.size()` and `.count()` *without* the `applySkipLimit` parameter set to true: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11881347/1709587