# Use cursor methods along with mongodb command in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cursor, geospatial, node-mongodb-native

I am working on a location based app in nodejs. I am using
 
- mongodb v2.4.4
- the native nodejs mongodb driver (https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native)
- nodejs version 0.10.0

I have geospatial indexes (2dsphere) in all the documents of one collection. The field is like this:

```
{ "loc" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [  -122.5418261,  38.0047656 ] } }
```

The name of the collection is **'Venue'**

To query data based on proximity to a particular point, I am using this code:

```
var query = {
            geoNear:"Venue",
            near : { type : "Point" ,
                coordinates: [ searchParams.longitude, searchParams.latitude ] } ,
            spherical : true,
            limit: 10000,
            maxDistance : searchParams.radius
        };


mongodbconnection.command(query, function(error, data){

});
```

**The geospatial query is working fine. But I want to filter the results further by using cursor object methods like skip() and limit().** But the data object returned in the callback is not a cursor. So how do I use skip() and limit() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    center = [-122, 37];
    radius = 80;
    var query = {"loc" : {"$within" : {"$center" : [center, radius]}}};


    collection.find(query).skip(2000).toArray(function(err,data){


        console.log(data.length);

    });
```

Courtesy: [MongoDB Geospatial Query Count Issue (Always 100)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542604/mongodb-geospatial-query-count-issue-always-100)

Comment: $within is deprecated...use $geoWithin ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/geoWithin/#op._S_geoWithin ) or $nearSphere ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nearSphere/#op._S_nearSphere ). If using $geoWithin use centersphere as the bounding geometry ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/centerSphere/#op._S_centerSphere ). $geoWithin is faster than $nearSphere since it does not sort results according to distance

Answer (score 0):

Please use `.find` instead of executing `.command` directly to database:

```
db.collection('Venue', function(err, venues) {
  // you might want to cache collection handler after
  if (!err) {
    venues.find({ $near: { $geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ searchParams.longitude, searchParams.latitude ] }, $maxDistance: searchParams.radius }, { limit: 32 }).toArray(function(err, data) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(data);
      } else {
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

You can include your cursor options as in example above (as object), or as cursor extensions like within command line as you get use to.